# Port mapping confusion in Nomad

Tags: nomad

I have the following basic nginx Nomad job:

```
job "hello" {
  datacenters = ["aus01"]

  group "hello" {
    network {
      port "http" {
        to = 80  # <--- Notice the port 80 specified here
      }
    }

    service {
      name     = "hello"
      provider = "nomad"
      port     = "http"

      tags = ["ingress"]

      meta {
        hostname = "ironforge.x17.space"
      }
    }

    task "hello" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "nginx"
        ports = ["http"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my ingress configuration, I map to `hello` service's dynamic address and port:

```
ingress:
{{- range nomadService "hello" }}
- service: http://{{ .Address }}:{{ .Port }}
  hostname: ironforge.x17.space
{{- end }}
```

This renders as:

```yaml
ingress:
- service: http://192.168.86.36:28868
  hostname: ironforge.x17.space
```

However, I do not understand why I need to specify the port 80 in my `hello` group network stanza, and why ingress stops working if I remove that.

[The documentation states](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/network#to):

> `to (string:nil)` - Applicable when using "bridge" mode to configure port to map to inside the task's network namespace. Omitting this field or setting it to -1 sets the mapped port equal to the dynamic port allocated by the scheduler. The NOMAD_PORT_ environment variable will contain the to value.

So why does my ingress stop working if the mapped port is set to be dynamic? After all, the final ingress configuration does not even reference the 80 port in any way.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> driver = "docker"
> ```

Inside the docker container, which has a virtualized network interface, there is an nginx application running that listens *on port 80*. On port 80 *on that virtualized* network interface inside the container.

`to = 80` tells Nomad to redirect a dynamically allocated port in the range 20000-32000 on a **real** network interface to the port 80 on that virtualized network interface exposed to the docker container.

Consider researching an introduction to docker. It's typical to `docker run -p 1234:80` do ports redirects while working with it.